# What does "tu lk" mean?

Tags: significado, jerga-internet

> tu lk

I received this text from a Nicaraguan. Can anyone tell me what it means? I checked with several online sources, however could not find any definition for this texting.

Comment: Could you provide some context?

Comment: I've seen that as an "abbreviation" of "loco". But I'm not sure whether this the only "standard" meaning

Comment: Any context? So, you received it in a text, what was the previous message?

Answer (score 4):

Bueno, eso no es español, ni dialecto nicaragüense, ni nada que se le parezca.

Por desgracia, mucha gente, sobre todo los jóvenes, para 
escribir con rapidez en su teléfono móvil suelen emplear abreviaturas fonéticas o acrónimos no convencionales, que a veces solo sus amiguetes entienden o pueden descifrar.

Y digo por desgracia, porque algunos ya han nacido con el móvil en la mano y sin control paterno, y están tan viciados por esta costumbre que llegan a considerar normal escribir así en cualquier contexto, ya sea un foro de Internet o el examen de literatura. Y cuando se ven forzados a escribir formalmente, pueden cometer faltas de ortografía tremebundas.

En este caso, como dice belisarius, podría ser  "tú estás loco" pero vaya usted a saber.

Hay una frase hecha para  para pedir que te den el mensaje de forma que lo puedas entender: "Háblame en cristiano". Seguramente proviene de los tiempos de la Reconquista, cuando los cristianos con sus amalgamas de latín y lenguas romances se entendían mas o menos entre ellos, pero no con los musulmanes o judíos. No es una frase muy cortés, pero no habrá problema si hay cierto grado de confianza (excepto ante un español que te habla en catalán, vasco o gallego, porque posiblemente lo tomará como un insulto).